# how to make a row of images in a bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a row of 3-5 images with titles above them in the body of a bootstrap modal. I've tried many times, but I just can't seem to figure out why it doesn't work... This is the code I'm working with.

What's happening is the images are not displaying inline, rather they are just stacked on top of each other. I would like them to lay out in a row below the main video.

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="tutorialModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="tutorialModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title tut-title" id="tutorialModal"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe class="tut-vid" width="865" height="480" src="" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <!-- Original Ratio Scaled to width="853" height="480" -->
        <p class="Pack-Quote">
          <!-- Enter Tutorial Description here. (If suitable) -->
        </p>

      </div>
      <!-- Try making these buttons control the Prev. and Next buttons for the Youtube playlist the current video is in -->
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <!-- This section will be used as a "Suggested Video Display" showing multiple thumbnails that are relatable to the video, or have been manually added. -->

        <div class="row">

          <div class "col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
              <h5>Tutorial</h5>
              <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class "col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
              <h5>Tutorial</h5>
              <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class "col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
              <h5>Tutorial</h5>
              <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class "col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
              <h5>Tutorial</h5>
              <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary align-left" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>Previous Tutorial</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary align-right" role="button">Next Tutorial<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 12/6= 2 and 12/3 = 4 :) So 2 or 4 images

Comment: Any combination should work, say 12/4 to provide room for 3 == images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I made a silly mistake by not adding = after div class for each column div..

for instructing purposes this following code will make it a row of 4 thumbnails within a bootstrap modal. Place the following code inside the modal's `<div class="modal-header">`, `<div class="modal-body">` or `<div class="modal-footer">` for the content to display correctly.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"> 
        <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
            <h5>Tutorial</h5>
            <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"> 
        <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
            <h5>Tutorial</h5>
            <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"> 
        <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
            <h5>Tutorial</h5>
            <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"> 
        <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
            <h5>Tutorial</h5>
            <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

If all you want is a row of images, just replace each column with the following.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <img src="Your image URL goes here" alt="Visual impared Text goes here">
</div>
```

Comment: Correct, these are actually place-filler IDs. For example, each one would be different according to the tutorial thumbnail & link being displayed in its position.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in each one and then tell me what happened

```
<div class "col-xs-6 col-md-3" style="float:left;">
      <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
        <h5>Tutorial</h5>
        <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: This method works, but it crams them altogether smaller, to the left side.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="tutorialModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="tutorialModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title tut-title" id="tutorialModal"></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe class="tut-vid" width="865" height="480" src="" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            <!-- Original Ratio Scaled to width="853" height="480" -->
            <p class="Pack-Quote">
              <!-- Enter Tutorial Description here. (If suitable) -->
            </p>

          </div>
          <!-- Try making these buttons control the Prev. and Next buttons for the Youtube playlist the current video is in -->
          <div class="modal-footer">

            <!-- This section will be used as a "Suggested Video Display" showing multiple thumbnails that are relatable to the video, or have been manually added. -->

            <div class="row">

              <div class = "col-xs-3" style="float:left;">
                <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
                  <h5>Tutorial</h5>
                  <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
                </a>
              </div>

              <div class = "col-xs-3" style="float:left;">
                <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
                  <h5>Tutorial</h5>
                  <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
                </a>
              </div>

              <div class = "col-xs-3" style="float:left;">
                <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
                  <h5>Tutorial</h5>
                  <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
                </a>
              </div>

              <div class = "col-xs-3" style="float:left;">
                <a class="thumbnail" id="TutorialID" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#tutorialModal" data-title="Tutorial Title" data-video="Youtube Video Embed Here...">
                  <h5>Tutorial</h5>
                  <img src="https://img.you|tube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg" alt="147x110">
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary align-left" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>Previous Tutorial</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary align-right" role="button">Next Tutorial<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```